# Tip on memory managment, objective c

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

i've an application with many view of graphic data (many labels, some images ecc), all these data is static, created in Interface builder and not connected to code because i don't need them.

I've seen that changing view the memory value increases, but the doesn't the system remove these type of objects itself?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it would be better if you connect them (IBOutlet) to your code and release them in your dealloc and viewDidUnload method.

1. connect:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIUserInterfaceElementClass *anOutlet;
   ```
2. release:

   ```
   [anOutlet release], anOutlet = nil;
   ```